# Where should generated header files be generated to? How can I then export them with catkin?

Tags: ros, catkin, headers, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(datatypes)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
catkin_package(
->INCLUDE_DIRS ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_GLOBAL_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#  LIBRARIES rtdb_config
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS other_catkin_pkg
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})
FILE(GLOB DATATYPE_RAW ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/datatypes/*)
add_custom_target(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ALL
    COMMAND generate_some_header_files_to ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
    SOURCES ${DATATYPE_RAW}
)
```

Where the custom command generates header files to be used by other packages in the dir ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}. (Not sure this dir should be used!!)

The problem seems to be that since this directory was still not created it fails to be exported by catkin_package:

```
catkin_package() include dir '/home/.../devel/include' is neither an absolute directory nor exists relative to '/home/.../src/rtdb/src/datatypes'
```

Now the question:
Where should generated header files be generated to? How can I then export them with catkin?

Thanks in advance.

Luis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123221/where-should-generated-header-files-be-generated-to?-how-can-i-then-export-them-with-catkin?/) by [loliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/10831/loliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your approach described in the question was almost right. As the CMake error indicates the path you specified as `catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS ...)` must exist when the function is being invoked. Therefore you have to move the `MAKE_DIRECTORY` line above the function. But since the function is also responsible to define the catkin DESTINATION variables you need to get them explicitly before using `catkin_destinations()`.

Further more you need to export your target which is responsible to generate the headers in order for downstream packages be able to cleanly depend on them being generated before. Usually you should pass `EXPORTED_TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_headers` to catkin (but due to a bug until now you have to set the variable `${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS` instead).

Last but not least you need to install the header files.

The complete example would then look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(datatypes)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

catkin_destinations()
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})
file(GLOB DATATYPE_RAW ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/datatypes/*)

# using a better target name for the custom target
add_custom_target(${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_headers
  ALL
  COMMAND generate_some_header_files_to ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  SOURCES ${DATATYPE_RAW}
)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_headers)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_GLOBAL_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  # instead of set(${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS ...)
  # but will only work as of catkin 0.5.81
  # EXPORTED_TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_headers
)

# no need for patterns / excludes since the path should only contain the generated headers
# by using the directory name with a slash at the end
# the directory name and destination become more natural
# (both mentioning CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION)
install(
  DIRECTORY ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [loliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/10831/loliveira/) on 2014-01-28**:
Perfect... that seems to be exactly what I'm looking for... unfortunately the good config breaks the compilation :) (my fault this time) ;) Only using catkin 0.5.79 so I'll use the first option.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [recommended solution](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/building_libraries.html#installing) is to mention your `include/` subdirectory to `catkin_package()`:

```
catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include)
```

Then, follow standard ROS practice and place all external header files under `include/your_package/`, and install them this way:

```
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-01-28**:
This does not address the question regarding generated headers.

**Comment by [loliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/10831/loliveira/) on 2014-01-28**:
So your suggestion is to place the generated header files in the src directory? I've thought about that but usualy compiletime generated files go to the build directory.

The install step works fine, I install to
*sorry next comment*

**Comment by [loliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/10831/loliveira/) on 2014-01-28**:
install(DIRECTORY ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h" PATTERN "*.hpp"
PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-01-28**:
As Dirk said, I overlooked the "generated" part of your question and answered only the "where to install" part. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time.

**Comment by [loliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/10831/loliveira/) on 2014-01-28**:
Don't worry, all help is welcome even if it overlooks some part of the question ;)